# How fetch model from nested resource backend in emberjs

Tags: ember.js

how I can fetch models nested in Ember.js. I means, I have a model called `post`. In my endpoint I have a route to fetch all `posts` and to fetch a specific `post` with its `id`. But, for example, if I show a specific `post`, how can I get all `comments` related with that `post` clicking in a button?

My route in backend is `/posts/:post_id/comments` .

Thanks

Comment: Could you post some code that you've tried? There are a few ways to go about this.

Comment: As far as I know there is no straight Ember way to deal with nested resources api. There is long discussion about nested resources api support: http://github.com/emberjs/data/issues/186, http://github.com/emberjs/rfcs/pull/4. If you manage the backend, you might find it is simpler to change backend api to avoid using nested resources.

Comment: By nested do you mean embedded?

Answer (score 3):

You could try [ember-data-url-templates](https://github.com/amiel/ember-data-url-templates) addon.

It allows specify urls you need by url templates. Now `ember-data-url-templates` is under early development.

```
// console
ember install ember-data-url-templates
ember generate ember-data-url-templates

// adapters/comment.js
// add UrlTemplates mixin to your `Adapter` and specify url templates 
import DS from "ember-data";
import UrlTemplates from "ember-data-url-templates";

export default DS.RESTAdapter.extend(UrlTemplates, {
  urlTemplate: '{+host}/posts/{postId}/comments{/id}',

  urlSegments: {
    postId(type, id, snapshot, query) {
      return snapshot.belongsTo('post', { id: true });
    }
  }

});
```

Comment: is it still something that we should do ?

Comment: If I were you I'd submit PR to update "ember-data-url-templates" for ember-data 2.0. I am sure there are some words to change only.

Comment: I would like but I just started ember last week. Seems a little bit early. :)

Comment: Agree :) I'll try to look at this on weekend.

Comment: FWIW: I've been using ember-data-url-templates for ~ 6 months in production. Let me know if you end up trying it and run in to any issues :)

Answer (score 2):

The best way I have found to access nested resources (if you can modify your API) is for your API to return a "links" attribute in the json for comments. For example the json returned will be like:

```
{
    "post": {
        "id": 1,
        "links": {
            "comments": "http://localhost:3000/posts/1/comments"
        }
    }
}
```

Now you define the relationship in your ember app and fetch the model in the route:

```
// models/post.js

import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.Model.extend({
  comments: DS.hasMany('comments', {async: true}); 
});

// models/comment.js

import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.Model.extend({
  post: DS.belongsTo('post', {async: true}); 
});


// post.js
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function(params) {
         return this.store.find('post', params.post_id);
    }    
});
```

Now, when in your template when you call

```
{{#each model.comments as |comment|}}
     {{comment.comment_attribute}}
{{/each}}
```

Ember will make a async request at /posts/:post_id/comments and fetch the comments. If you wish to show a loading icon or something while the request is taking place you can wrap it in

```
   {{#if model.comments}}
     {{#each model.comments as |comment|}}
       {{comment.comment_attribute}}
     {{/each}}
   {{else}}
      <!-- Something to do while loading -->
   {{/if}}
```

Note :You can also see this documented in 
[Ember Doc](http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.RESTAdapter.html#method_findHasMany)

This findHasMany method is called when ember sees in your template {{model.comments}}

The second solution for your problem would be to customize the adapter while in your route (I dont recommend this and havent really tested it):

```
//one post route

import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Route.extend({
   model: function(params) {
      return this.store.findRecord('post', params.post_id);  
   }
});

//post/comments route

import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Route.extend({
   model: function() {
      var post_id = this.modelFor('post.show').get('id');
      this.store.adapterFor('comment').set('namespace', 'posts/' + post_id );
     var comments = this.store.findAll('comment');
     // set the namespace again to null 
     this.store.adapterFor('comment').set('namespace', '');
     return comments;
   }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Extending @filby's answer further with JSON API 1.0 specification which uses the new `JSONAPIAdapter`, the following code works

**Single Post response from server**

```
'data': {
    'type': 'posts',
    'id': 1,
    'attributes': {
        'title:'A new post'
    },
    'relationships': {
        'comments': {
            'links':{
                'related': '/api/posts/1/comments'
             }
         }
    }
}
```

**The Post model**

```
// models/post.js

import Model from 'ember-data/model';
import attr from 'ember-data/attr';
import { hasMany } from 'ember-data/relationships';

export default Model.extend({
  title: attr('string')
  comments: hasMany('comments'); 
});
```

**The Comments model**

```
// models/comment.js

import Model from 'ember-data/model';
import attr from 'ember-data/attr';
import { belongsTo } from 'ember-data/relationships';

export default Model.extend({
  post: belongsTo('post', {async: true}); 
  likes: attr('number')
});
```

**The Post's Route**

```
// post.js
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function(params) {
         return this.store.findRecord('post', params.post_id);
    }    
});
```

**The Post template**

```
{{#each model.comments as |comment|}}
     {{comment.likes}}
{{/each}}
```

The requests for comments will be `/api/posts/1/comments` which is specified in the `related` attribute.

Answer (score 0):

You can make a custom buildUrl in your rest adapter.

Mine that I'm currently using (only for `/posts/:post_id/comments` )

```
export default DS.RESTAdapter.extend({
    host: 'http://www.exemple.me:3000',
    namespace: 'api/v1/,
    buildURL: function (modelName, id, snapshot, requestType, query) {
      var url = [];
      url.push(this.urlPrefix());
      url.push("posts/" + query.post);
      delete query.user;
      url.push(this.pathForType(modelName));
      return url.join('/') + ".json";
    }
});
```